# How do I set up an OS level proxy when a specific application does not support it?

Tags: networking, proxy, connection, redirection

I'm running a certain desktop app (actually Youwave Android) which doesn't have any built-in proxy configuration settings.

I need to get all traffic just from this app directed through a proxy.

Comment: Are you on a mac or PC?

Comment: @MichaelPryor [Youwave](http://youwave.com/) appears to be Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cascading proxy like CCProxy http://www.youngzsoft.net or a transparent proxy like Proxifier http://proxifier.com/